# Any way to add rownames to a tibble in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, tidyverse

I'm trying to change the `rowname`s in a `tibble` outputted by a `map_dfr` looping function from the `purrr` package below without success. Is there a fix?

```
foo <- function(x){
     total <- rbinom(1, x, .5)
     fixed <- total - 2
    random <- fixed + 3
   c(total = total, fixed = fixed, random = random)
}

m <- purrr::map_dfr(.x = c(6:9), .f = foo) # loop and output a tibble (a data.frame)
rownames(m) <- paste0("m", 1:4) # change the rownames
m
```

BUT `rownames` don't change:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  total fixed random
* <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     2     0      3
2     3     1      4
3     4     2      5
4     2     0      3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a `tibble` and tibble cannot have a custom row name.  An option is to convert to `data.frame` and then assign the row names

```
m <- as.data.frame(m)
rownames(m) <- paste0("m", 1:4)
m
#   total fixed random
#m1     3     1      4
#m2     5     3      6
#m3     2     0      3
#m4     5     3      6
```

---

If we want to keep a column for identification, the `map`, also have `.id` which will include either the `list` name (if present) or the sequence of the `list`

```
purrr::map_dfr(.x = 6:9, .f = foo, .id = 'm')
purrr::map_dfr(.x = setNames(6:9, paste0("m", 1:4)), .f = foo, .id = 'm')
```

Comment: @rnorouzian according to documentation [here](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/rownames.html), it is allowed to have a column and not as rowname

Comment: @rnorouzian it is a technical limitation for tibble and data.table

Comment: @rnorouzian if there is an existing row.names, it will strip it i.e. `mtcars %>% as_tibble`

Comment: @rnorouzian I meant the 6:9 as length 4.  If you already have a list.  Then `map_dfr(setNames(lst1, paste0("m", seq_along(lst1))), .f = foo, .id = 'm')`